# Following two different motion guides in Flash Professional CC

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is it possible to follow two different path in Flash Professional CC, when one end of a line should follow the first path, and the other end should follow the second path? Best without AS3?

Example: On the picture below you see a green line. The upper end should follow the left path, the lower end should follow the right path. Therefore, the size of the line should change as well - dynamicly!

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about motion guides?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seeing your image I would say this is not possible (at least not with one object).

What you should do is:
1. Create your paths
2. Create two invisible objects, one for each path and attach them to your paths
3. Create a 'canvas' sprite and use an enter frame event or a timer to draw the line, something like:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

var canvas:Sprite = new Sprite();

canvas.graphics.lineStyle(1);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    canvas.graphics.clear();
    canvas.graphics.moveTo(o1.x, o1.y);
    canvas.graphics.lineTo(o2.x, o2.y);
}
```

Where o1 = your insvisible display object on the one side, o2 the other.